# How do I generate a list of pages in the sections for a sidemenu in Wagtail?

Tags: django-models, django-templates, wagtail

I am a true beginner in Wagtail. How do I generate a list of pages in the sections for a sidemenu in Wagtail?

I have the following site structure, as an example:

```
home/
    fruits/
        apples/
        oranges/
        grapes/
    vegetables/
        kale/
        spinach/
        cabbage/
```

`home` is of `HomePage` type using `home_page.html` template , and all the subpages are of `ContentPage` type using `content_page.html` template.

I want to make a side menu for all the content pages, listing all the pages in their groups. For example, this list:

```
Fruits
Apples
Oranges
Grapes
```

should be the sidemenu for the pages `fruits`, `apple`, `oranges`, and `grapes`.

`page.get_children` in the template only lists out if the page has children, so, in this case just `fruits` and `vegetables`.

How would I go about making that sidemenu?

The examples in Wagtail's documentation seem to imply that I can't have just a generic content type like `ContentPage` to have the sort of listing that I want, is that true?

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

welcome to Wagtail!

As with most things in web development, there are a few ways you can do this. The simplest to understand when you're just starting is to do this all through the template. So in your `home_page.html` you could have:

```
{% for parent in page.get_children %}
    Page title: {{ parent.title }} <br />

    {% if parent.get_children.count %}
        {% for child in parent.get_children %}
            - Child page title: {{ child.title }}<br/>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

What this does is:

1. Loops through the child pages of HomePage (labeled as `parent` in this loop) and prints `Page title: {title_here}`
2. Then it'll check for child pages of each `parent` loop iteration and print `- Child page title: {child_title}`

There's a gotcha here though. This will only work on the `home_page.html` template. Once you go to `/fruits/` it'll try to perform the same logic, but this time it'll think `Fruits` is the new `HomePage`

There are 2 options you can take from here.

1. You can add custom context to every page to make sure you're always passing in the `HomePage` and loop through that. This is the simplest method and I'll show you the code below. Or,
2. You can create a Menu system using a Django Model and registering the Menu class as a Wagtail Snippet. I have a video with all the source code available if you want to take a deeper dive into Wagtail (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y8a9ROUUJXU)

To add `HomePage` to every `ContentPage` you can add it to the context of every page, like so:

```py
class ContentPage(Page):

    # Fields here

    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Adding HomePage to your page context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context["home_page"] = HomePage.objects.first()
        return context
```

And in your templates you'd write:

```
    {% for child_page in home_page.get_children %}
        Page title: {{ child_page.title }} <br />

        {% if child_page.get_children.count %}
            {% for grandchild_page in child_page.get_children %}
                - Child page title: {{ grandchild_page.title }}<br/>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
```

**Edit:** If you're on a grandchild page, like `/fruits/apples/` and want to display the parent page title, and all the sibling pages (ie. `/fruits/oranges/` and `/fruits/grapes/`) you can loop through the sibling pages. Something like this should work:

```
<!-- On `/fruits/` this will be the Home Page title. On `/fruits/apples/` this will be the Fruits page title. -->
<h2>{{ self.get_parent.title }}<h2>

{% for sibling in self.get_siblings %}
   <a href="{{ sibling.url }}">{{ sibling.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```